# Array $txt[$y] loses special characters

Tags: php, fpdf

I have to encode this `$txt[$y]` bellow to utf-8 or ISO-8859-1. I use tFPDF extend with font with have special letters. Right now string is correctly displayed in the cell, but when I use special letters like ś,й,é I can see only question marks:
[image: img here]

```
function magia($txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='C', $fill=false, $link='', $scale=false, $force=true){
    $str_width = $this->GetStringWidth($txt);
    $len = strlen($txt);

    for ($y = 0; $y < $len; $y++){
        $this->Cell(6,6,$txt[$y],0,0,'C');        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `print_r()`?

Comment: @Progman to cut a string into individual letters. Look img.

Comment: That's not what `print_r()` does. You don't need it here, you simply use the value `$txt[$y]`.

Comment: Yes this work, but still like on img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mb_` functions. PHP is still not full UTF-8 friendly.
Doing `$x[0]` will not work on some special characters. Use for example `mb_substr()` function to get characters. There is a lot of `mb_` string functions equal to normal functions that can operate on selected charsets.

`mb_substr($str,1,1)` will fetch second letter.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

`+1` for `magia` :D

Comment: This is my savior ! +